# Which Stack Exchange site should I use for questions about the Mac terminal?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question about changing the value of the `$PATH` variable in OS X. I am not sure if it should go under Super User or under Apple Stack Exchange.

Comment: Looks like Apple.SE already has a number of those, so it should be a safe bet: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=path+variable

Comment: Cheers @Pekka I'll check it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) does look like it can handle questions like that, yes.

Comment: Cheers! That answers my question. I cannot upvote you due to my small reputation, but you have my thanks!